# Why doesn't the function in this class use an updated class attribute?

Tags: python, class, attributes

As seen below, updating a class attribute does not change the value of the attribute used in the init function, but does change the value used for the following class function. Why is this the case?

I'm just starting to tinker with classes so I am not sure what alternatives to try.

```
class Employee:

 def __init__(self, first, last, pay): 
    self.first = first              
    self.last = last
    self.pay = pay
    self.email = first + '.' + last + '@company.com'

def fullname(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

emp_1 = Employee('Micheal', 'scoot', 50000)
emp_1.last = 'Scott'        

print(emp_1.email)       # - > Micheal.scoot@company.com  
print(emp_1.fullname())  # - > Micheal Scott
```

The comments above show the outputs I recieved. I expected the email function to use the updated last name of 'Scott' instead of 'scoot'.

Comment: I see this example is from Corey Schafer videos, there is a video about property constructor where he explains how to achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only calculate self.email in the init function during creation of emp_1. When you change emp_1.last, it doesn't retrigger the line that calculates the email. You could get the behaviour you want by adding a function for the email:

```py
def email(self):
    return self.first + '.' + self.last + '@company.com'

...

print(emp_1.email())
```

Comment: I think its time for me to go to bed.

Answer (score 3):

you need to turn `email` into a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) if you want this behavior (and you should probably do the same for `fullname`):

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self.first + "." + self.last + "@company.com"
        # return f"{self.first}.{self.last}@company.com"

    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first, self.last)
        # return f"{self.first} {self.last}"
```

this will work as expected now:

```
emp_1 = Employee('Micheal', 'scoot', 50000)
emp_1.last = 'Scott'        
print(emp_1.email)       # -> Micheal.Scott@company.com 
print(emp_1.fullname)    # now without parentheses! -> Micheal Scott
```

in your original code you assign `self.email` in the constructor. this way it will not get updated if you change `self.last` afterwards.